# How to get the current categories list in High Charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I need to get the current categories list of high charts

for example:

```
  var drilldown = this.drilldown;
  setChart([drilldown.name,drilldown.name1], drilldown.categories, 
  [drilldown.data,drilldown.data1]);
```

**drilldown.categories**
will fetch the categories of next drill down series

as well as **this.category** will fetch the category point if i am having [jan, feb, mar], **this.category** will fetch the jan if there is point

But i need the whole categories list of current series something like

```
this.series.name,
this.series.data
```

like wise i need something like **this.series.caetgories** but i cant find anything like that in high charts, is there anyway to fetch it

Comment: Can't you get it from `chart.xAxis[0].categories`?

Comment: yaa but using char.xAxis[0].categories i can able to take only x Axis categories, but, for me there are 3 categories, but 1st and 2nd category is assigned with a series , so chart.xAxis will not help me out

Comment: Well it is not clear for me, because all categoreis are kept in the xAxis object, so Im not sure what is wrong with it, still. Can you replciate your issue as live demo to introduce it?

Comment: Here is a fiddle Sebastian
http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedmusthafac/84AK5/2/
Just click any of the bars you will get alerted as undefined , i alerted as (this.categories), but it showing undefined